# Create Magento product that redirect to an external website

Tags: magento-1.9, product, url, websites

Hello any one can help me i will be very thankful to you....i want to add a product that is not held on my magento website only show on my website...but when customer click on product directly goes to the website that hold the product.
i want to give url to the product..how can i do...please help me thanks again..
here is some screen shot that show what actually what i want to do....

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDaQt.png

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom attribute, where you fill in the custom url. let's say "custom_url" as attribute code.

In your list.phtml you could do :

```
<?php
    if($_product->getCustomUrl()){ $url = $_product->getCustomUrl(); }
    else{ $url = $_product->getProductUrl(); }
?>
```

and use $url in href

Comment: This is simple way to achieve your need